# Testing the equality of Beta Estimates from Multiple (>2) Quantiles in Quantile Regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, anova, regression-coefficients, quantile-regression

I'm trying to determine whether Beta estimates at different quantiles obtained using quantile regression (`quantreg` package in R) are statistically different from each other. In reading the work of Roger Koenker ("Quanile Regression" 2005. pg 75-76) and Hao & Naiman ("Quantile Regression"2007. pg 47-51). This seems to be a relatively simple matter of constructing a Wald Statistic as follows.
$$
W= \frac{(\hat\beta_j^{(p)}-\hat\beta_j^{(q)})^2}{\hat\sigma^2_{(\hat\beta_j^{(p)}-\hat\beta_j^{(q)})}}
$$
Where $\hat\beta_j^{(p)}$ and $\hat\beta_j^{(q)}$ are the beta estimates for covariate $j$ at quantile $p$ and $q$, and $\sigma^2_{(\hat\beta_j^{(p)}-\hat\beta_j^{(q)})}$ is an estimate of the variance in those estimates as given by:
$$
\text{Var}\left(\hat\beta_j^{(p)}\right) + \text{Var}\left(\hat\beta_j^{(q)}\right) - 2\text{Cov} \left(\hat\beta_j^{(p)}, \hat\beta_j^{(q)}\right).
$$
When estimates of from two taus ($p$ and $q$) are compared this is straight forward enough. **But what about when more than two taus are compared?**

**So for taus $p$, $q$, and $r$, do i need to compare $p$ vs $q$, $p$ vs $r$, and $q$ vs $r$ ?** This problem escalates quickly when even more taus of interested are compared (in my case 19 taus = **171** unique combinations of $p$ and $q$).

My overall goal is to test whether for $n$ taus (quantiles)
$$H_0 : \hat\beta_j^{(i)}=\hat\beta_j^{(i+1)}\ldots=\hat\beta_j^{(n)}$$
$$H_1 : \hat\beta_j^{(i)}\neq\hat\beta_j^{(i+1)}\ldots\neq\hat\beta_j^{(n)}$$

Comment: no love on this question?

Comment: haha earned Tumbleweed achievement for this question

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245558/.

Comment: Did you solve the problem eventually?