# Cross model comparison of quantile regression coefficients

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, quantile-regression

I am looking for a way to compare coefficients obtained from quantile regression.
The two surveyed models are **nested**, estimated on the **same sample** and for the **same quantile**.
$$
Y = \beta_1X+\epsilon_2\\
Y = \beta_2X+\gamma Z + \epsilon_1
$$
Given the estimates and the respective standard errors I want to know if $\beta_1$ and $ \beta_2$ differ significantly.
All I could find up to now are tests for coefficient differences between regressions for different quantiles or for different groups (samples).

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, could you perhaps contribute to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175587/ and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124796/?